# now for the gravy... -- meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Usage example with a context:

> With that, we have completed the design of our database and implemented it in Access. Overall, this makes for a very simple database implementation and the application prototyping can begin.
>   **Now for the gravy...** the database built in Access can be upsized to an enterprise SQL Server database with just a few clicks. Access provides a built-in Upsizing Wizard that makes the process very simple.

How do you understand that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have prepared the meal itself: the database. We have done the bulk of the job and in principle met (almost) all our objectives for the course.

Now we can engage in the preparation of a side-dish: the gravy. The database itself is a working product, ready for use, just like a plate of boiled potatoes is ready for use.

But after the easy step of upsizing it, it will be even better, just like a plate of potatoes will be better with a ladle or two of gravy added to it.

We can rephrase

> Now for the gravy...

as

> Now let's see what additional job we can do to make the database better.

or

> The database is complete and is ready for work. Now let's see what additional steps could be taken to make it work even better.

Comment: Delicious explanation :-) But a gravy quibble: although we see in diner menus (e.g. http://www.villageinn.com/menu/) phrases such as "scrambled eggs smothered with country sausage gravy *atop* two potato pancakes" I don't think we can use "atop of" to describe gravy that has been ladled onto potatoes. To be 'atop of' something means to be *positioned* there, but gravy per se is unpositionable. We could make this a question and see if other native speakers feel the same about "atop" as I do, if they're not too busy with actual gravy today.

Comment: @TRomano If you don't shape the potatoes right, then it's unpositionable, but I like to build a little volcano to keep my gravy atop my spuds.  ;-p

Comment: Thank you, @TRomano, for the comment! I changed the text a bit. Should you gravitate towards the opinion that the gravy question is grave enough for a new ELL question, then I won't question your making a new ELL question of it, and let the best answer be engraved in the annals of ELL, or atop of them. (0: